# How can I find users from a specific country?

Tags: support, search, users

I want to know if I can search Stack Overflow users by their country. For example, I had, like, to see all users who live in the UK.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) to find the users which have a specific `Location` set in their profile (note that this only uses public data, and doesn't use gathered information on usage locations).

You could try [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/139704/top-uk-users-by-quant-tag-and-location) for example. If this doesn't meet your exact requirements, you could fork it and create your own.

There is no way to search for users' locations using the site directly and I think it is against the philosophy of SE to do so. It would emphasize too much the user's origin, while that doesn't matter for the Q/A site.

Comment: Right. The location is user inputted. So some users could be "lying" about their location. Many users don't have any location set. So there is no way for you to see all users who live in a specific country.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a SEDE query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/301624/users-by-location) that you might find helpful.   As said in a comment, the data is input by the users, and may not be accurate, and some users (myself included) do not have location data set.